# An unfair dice question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Unfair die of 12 faces. The number 11 has a chance of  40% while other
>   faces are equally likely. If someone and you are playing a game and
>   whoever is closer to the answer will win, what is your strategy? Also, do
>   you start first or second?

So I believe the best strategy is to pick $8$ because the expected value of this dice is given by $8.05454546$

Also, I think it's best to go second because my opponent can just choose the bigger part of my numbers. For example, if I choose $11$, they can choose $10$, and they'll have $6/11$ chance to win.

Is this right? I don't know if there's a better strategy.

Comment: I haven´t understood what "the answer" in this context means? It sounds a bit mysterious.

Comment: I want to devise a strategy that makes me the most money, and greatest chance of winning.

Comment: But what is "the answer". A movie title?

Comment: Whoever is closest to the outcome of the unfair $12$ sided dice will win.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is 10

If you pick 10, and your opponent picks 9, they will win if the dice is 1-9. That means there is a 9/11 * 60% = 49% chance of winning. However, if your opponent picks 11, then there is a 1/11 * 60% + 40% = 45% chance of winning. Either way, you've won because your opponent is always under 50%